# Enterprise Library: How to add data to Task Category in Windows Event Log entry?

Tags: enterprise-library, event-log

When using Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0, how do we have the Logging Block enter data into the Task Category field of the event Log entry without specifically creating an event log entry in code?

My Enterprise Library categories show up just fine but that is not what we filter the Windows Event Log with so a Task Category entry would be nice.

But also I want to use the generic logging calls in code and not specifically instantiate a Windows Log entry i.e. I want to keep:

```
// Create a LogWriter object.
LogWriter writer = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();

// Use the LogWriter object.
writer.Write("My message", "kicks");
```

But somehow also have the Task Category field completed.

[image]